# JQuery ~ How to keep moving the object when keydown

Tags: jquery

In JQuery ~
I hope to make a simple character moving, Stop > Left || right.

This script make #moveCharacter turn left walk 10px **once**.

How can I *keydown* keep turn left **walking**,when *keyup* stop walking (like a character)??

```
// Left moving
$(document).keydown(function(e){

    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
      $("#moveCharacter").animate({marginLeft: "-=10px"}, {queue:false});
       return false;
    }
});
```

2.I try to change keypress() but it has not work.....what wrong?

```
var xTriggered = 0;
$(document).keypress(function(e){
   xTriggered++;
    if (e.which == '37') { 

      $("#moveCharacter").animate({marginLeft: "-="+xTriggered+"px"}, {queue:false});
       return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this code will work as you want

```
    var xTriggered = 0;
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
    xTriggered++;
    if (e.which == '37') { 
    $("#moveCharacter").animate({marginLeft: "-="+xTriggered+"px"}, {queue:false});
          return false;
        }
```

//EDIT

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
$("#moveCharacter").animate({ marginLeft: "-=10"}); 
}  
});
   $(document).keyup(function(e) { 
 $("#moveCharacter").queue("fx", []);
  $("#moveCharacter").stop();   });
```

Comment: It work but not smooth. 1.When keydown it move a little px. 2.then holding the key it faster and faster 3.keyout it run away.I hope that keep a speed like character walking .

Answer (score 4):

You want to be using the keypress event instead of keydown. As per the [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> If the user presses and holds a key, a keydown event is triggered once, but separate keypress events are triggered for each inserted character

Comment: I only change to use $(document).keypress(function(e){ but it has not work